# Drawing individual polygons - buildings, country borders, etc on a map (looping through index buffer) in WebGL

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, polygons, index-buffer

I am using WebGL to draw lines and polygons on a canvas layer on top of my map for OSM data. I have written a query that returns a list of polygons from the `planet_osm_polygon` table. It returns the list as JSON objects. I am using

```
 gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, vetexIndex.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

To draw the polygons.

My index buffer looks like this:

```
pIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pIndexBuffer); 
pVertexIndices = new Uint16Array([0,1, 1,2, 2,3]);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pVertexIndices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Here, for the indices of the polygon, I have used 0,1 1,2 and 2,3 as pairs, which draws a three consecutive lines (as border surrounding the polygon) 
 I would want to draw several other polygons like this. Without the use of drawElements() and index buffers, using just drawArrays() and gl.LINE_STRIP as so:

```
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINESTRIP, 0, json_data_length)
```

Draws the polygons but connects one end of each polygon with the next one (since it is a LINE_STRIP).

How can I draw separate individual polygons on my map? How can I use my index buffer here, for each polygon?

I do not want to use any external library; just plain JavaScript. I have already converted the lat-long coordinates from my OSM database into pixel coordinates in my JavaScript code.

using gl.LINE_STRIP

[image]

using gl.LINES and an index buffer

[image]

Comment: Im a bit confused by your question. It seems you got the polygons drawing working properly via drawElements but then for some reason you dont want to use indices/drawElements and want to use drawArrays?

Comment: No. I have plotted points on my map; these points form the border of the polygons. Then, I am trying to draw lines, connecting these points so that a polygon would be rendered. I used drawArrays initially. This seems to have drawn the polygons. But in drawArrays, i used LINE_STRIP, which connected even the endpoint of one polygon with the next polygon that I am drawing(the polygons were not drawn separately, they were connected). So, I resorted to using drawElements and tried to use an index buffer to connect points and draw the polygon.

Comment: With the above code, I am able to connect 3 points and draw 3 consecutive lines. of the polygon.

Comment: please see the link above; it contains screenshots of what I am trying to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you will be able to draw multiple polylines in a single draw call is to use GL_LINES.  When OpenGL goes to render a buffer using GL_LINES or GL_LINESTRIP it will need 2 vertices from your vertex buffer, and use these 2 point to draw a line.  The behavior of GL_LINES vs GL_LINESTRIP differs as follows:

GL_LINES:

```
line 1 - v[0], v[1]
line 2 - v[2], v[3]
line 3 - v[4], v[5]
...
```

GL_LINESTRIP

```
line 1 - v[0], v[1]
line 2 - v[1], v[2]
line 3 - v[2], v[3]
...
```

So as you can see, if you do not use GL_LINES, then you will not be able to disconnect the lines, and the lines will be considered one continuous polyline.  The only exception is if you insert a *degenerate* primitive, but this is an advanced technique that I do not recommend for a beginner such as yourself.

Best of luck.  Hope this solves your problem.

EDIT: My mistake, degenerate primitives only applies to GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, it is not possible to draw degenerates with GL_LINESTRIP.

Comment: I don't think using degenerate primitives would help for the line drawing case. It still won't allow you to draw disconnected lines with `GL_LINE_STRIP`.

Comment: So, should I try using gl.LINES in webgl instead?

Comment: @RetoKoradi you are correct, this applies only to GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Comment: @user4726090 yes, gl.LINES would be the WebGL equivalent.

Comment: but still, i am not able to draw individual polygons. Everytime I reload the page, webgl seems to draw only one polygon now, instead of 2.

Comment: If you are still not able to draw multiple polygons, this is almost certainly a bug with your code.  I would make sure all your vertex buffers are correct and use the WebGL Inspector chrome add-on to inspect your vertex buffers and draw calls to make sure that all of the state is set correctly.